# Making post requests in python

Tags: python, http, request, python-requests

When i  make this requests it returns code 200 which it should. But if i change sizeLoadedVarient or  colorLoadedID then checkout should not return true.

The first request should add an item to cart. The second request should only return 200 if there is something in the cart

Currently it is outputting

```
checkout ok
```

Even when it should return false

```
import requests

atcURL = "http://www.thenextopening.com/shop/111222/add.json"
sizeLoadedVarient = "40414"
colorLoadedID = "19824"
headers = user = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.4.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14D27 Safari/602.1"}

sessionProfile = requests.session()

senddata = {
'size' : sizeLoadedVarient,
'style' : colorLoadedID,
'qty' : 1
}

r = sessionProfile.post(atcURL,data=senddata, verify=False, headers=headers)

if (r.status_code == 200):
print("ATC ok")
r2 = sessionProfile.get("http://www.thenextshopopen.com/checkout")#.text
#print(r2)
if(r2.status_code == 200):
    print('checkout ok')
elif(r2.status_code != 200):
    print('checkout not ok')
else:
    print('checkout not ok')

elif (r.status_code != 200):
print("Atc not ok")
else:
print('atc not ok')
```

Comment: It's not clear what would you like to achieve and how your code is related to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` automatically follows redirects; in this case, you are being redirected back to the store page, which itself returns a 200. You can either disable the redirect by passing `allow_redirects=False` to `.get`, or you can verify `r2.url` is still the checkout path.